# Problem with Georeferencer not scaling TIFcorrectly

Tags: qgis, raster

I am trying to use QGIS and the Georeferencer to digitize paper maps but I am unable to get the raster to rotate afte I pick my control points.  Below is a brief outline of the steps I used to transform my raster.

1. Added two control points and picked corresponding points in map canvas.
2. The transformation type is set to Helmert
3. Resampling method: Cubic
4. Compression: Deflate
5. Specified Output file name
6. Checked "Load in Qgis...", then Ok
7. Then clicked run button.

The attached image is the results in QGIS.

[image]

The image should be much smaller

Comment: change of transformation type

Comment: What should it be changed to?

Comment: polynomial, for example

Comment: For two-point georeferencing I use Helmert and Linear. N.

Comment: and 2 points, it is too little

Comment: It depends gene, with good, undistorted images two points are fine. Obviously, the greater the x and y distances between the two points the better. N.

Comment: Get more points. if you are haviving issues it must be something to do with this. and change trasformation type.